# Activeadmin giving runtime error when use before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to add a global before_filter for admin. In my `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` i have

```
config.before_filter :do_something_awesome
```

and in `application_controller.rb`

```
def do_something_awesome
  # raise
end
```

When i try to start my server it stop with the following error.

```
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Student (RuntimeError)
```

And also can i use `before_action` rather than `before_filter` because Rails 4.2 deprecates `before_filter`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use before_action.

Comment: Check this link for better understanding the error, http://neethack.com/2015/04/rails-circular-dependency/